# How can I use web worker in ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, web-worker

I'm new to ionic and typescript, and I need to use web workers.
I found this:
 https://github.com/zlepper/typescript-webworker

but if I create the 3 files like suggested I get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file-loader'
```

Have I to change other thinks?

Answer (score 0):

Answered late but hope it helps others.

Web workers are officially supported from Angular 8.

[Angular official Doc](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker#adding-a-web-worker)

[Ionic Example implementation](https://dev.to/daviddalbusco/angular-and-web-workers-3mi7)

To add a web worker to an existing project, use the Angular CLI ng generate command.

```
ng generate web-worker <location>
```

The command performs the following actions.

- Configures your project to use web workers, if it isn't already.
- Adds the following scaffold code to src/app/app.worker.ts to receive
  messages.

  > addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  > const response = "worker response to ${data}";
  > postMessage(response);
  > });
- Adds the following scaffold code to src/app/app.component.ts to use the worker.

> ```
>   if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
>   // Create a new
>   const worker = new Worker('./app.worker', { type: 'module' });
>   worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
>     console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
>   };
>   worker.postMessage('hello');
> } else {
>   // Web workers are not supported in this environment.
>   // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
> }
> ```